# Doctrine 2 - How to search with DQL and grouping

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, dql

I can't figure out how i can **combine my LIKE search with grouping it by date and a category in DQL**..

**Explanation:**

I have a search function that search my events after weight.. it looks like this:

```
SELECT e as event,
  (CASE
     (e.name LIKE :searchterm) THEN 10
      ELSE 0
   END) +
   (CASE
      WHEN (e.name LIKE :searchtermFull) THEN 5
      ELSE 0
    END)

 AS weight

FROM
  \Entities\Event e

WHERE
  e.name LIKE :searchterm OR
  e.name LIKE :searchtermFull

  ORDER BY weight DESC
```

**This works fine, but now i want to have these searchresults grouped by year and date (not time) so my items is grouped like this**:

**27 jan:**

- event 1
- event 2

**28 jan:**

- event 3
- event 4

And i also need to do is to get it grouped my categories so i in the end will have:

**27 jan:**

- Category 1

  - Event 1
  - Event 2
- Category 2

  - Event 3

**My Database event table:**

- name varchar(255)
- description  varchar(255)
- created  datetime
- place_id int(11)
- eventdate    datetime
- organiser_id int(11)
- created_user_id  int(11)
- category int(11)

**My Database category table**

- id   int(11)
- name varchar(255)
- description  varchar(255)

I have a Event Entity and a EventCategory Entity and what the EventCategory does is just to bind the category id on to the Event Entity

--**Update - my sql so far**--

```
SELECT 
    c.name, 
    YEAR(e.eventdate) as year, 
    MONTH(e.eventdate) as month, 
    DAY(e.eventdate) as day, 
    count(*) as total 
FROM `events` as e, `eventCategories` as c 
WHERE
    e.category = c.id
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(e.eventdate),  
    MONTH(e.eventdate),
    DAY(e.eventdate)

ORDER BY eventdate ASC
```

The DoctrineExtensions is included by writing this in the autoloader:

$classLoader = new Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('DoctrineExtensions', ROOT.DS."library");
$classLoader->register();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use date functions DAY, MONTH or YEAR (**Mysql**)
Doctrine as is does not support these functions so you need to write your own ([DQL functions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html)) or install [this library](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions)

Group records by year, month

```
WHERE ... GROUP BY YEAR(eventdate), MONTH(eventdate) ORDER BY eventdate ASC
```

Group records by year, month and day

```
WHERE ... GROUP BY YEAR(eventdate), MONTH(eventdate), DAY(eventdate) ORDER BY eventdate ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I have installed the DoctrineExtensions like you said, but when i try to do a GROUP BY year statement then i get:  "Error: Cannot group by undefined identification or result variable." .. see what sql i try to do in dql in my post above..

Comment: have use DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql is in the top of the document

Comment: Your raw sql works for me, can you show your DQL with grouping?

Comment: I would also suggest to do a simple DQL, just to check
(something like: SELECT eventdate GROUP BY YEAR(eventdate))

Comment: In my DQL i have:        SELECT eventdate
          FROM \Entities\Event e
       GROUP BY YEAR(e.eventdate)

But it still says: Error: Cannot group by undefined identification or result variable.

Comment: That works for me, it must be extension not installed correct.
Try SELECT YEAR(e.eventdate) FROM \Entities\Event e?

Comment: Okay thats wierd.. i tried that but i get '[Syntax Error] line 0, col 9: Error: Expected known function, got 'YEAR'' in /usr/local/lib/php/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:42

Comment: Okay, that means doctrine extension I mentioned not installed.

Comment: ok, think this question is answered.. now i know how to use day and year on doctrine, and create a new on how to get that library work.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write your own function or install third party library. Since `datetime` is stored as string, you can use [Doctrine's function](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions) `SUBSTRING()` to extract certain part and group by it.

For example:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(e.eventdate, 1, 4) AS year FROM … GROUP BY year;
```